# Javascript: Atributting value to an id What is wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, variables, cookies

the thing here is, i have this code, and it was supposed to output the results of the variables into contact form 7 for wordpress hidden fields (i have the modules plugin to enable the hidden fields) that were sent by email, but i dont think the id i display is getting the value i attribute, i js linted the code and all it said was multiple variable declaration, which shouldnt be a problem since it's an if statement, so, there will never be a double declaration of the variable.

This is the code i use to transform the cookies created in my script (using jQuery.cookie) into text that is outputted to a table in my website, but more than outputting it to a table, i would like to email it to the user, i already have a contact-form 7 form prepared to do this, i just need to attribute the value of the returned variable (or at least one of them, the last  is the price, i dont need to send that by email) to the contact form field id, yesterday here in stackoverflow someone gave me that code to pass the value into contact form 7, but im afraid it isnt working :/

```
 function readRims() {
var rims_read = $.cookie('rim_color');
if (rims_read=="black" ) {
    var jantes = 'Pretas';
    var preco = 'Sob Consulta';
}
else if (rims_read=="silver"){
    var jantes = 'De Série';
    var preco = '';
}
else if (rims_read=="white"){
    var jantes = 'Brancas';
    var preco = 'Sob Consulta';
}
else if (rims_read=="titanium"){
    var jantes = 'Titanium';
    var preco = 'Sob Consulta';
}
else {
    var jantes = 'Escolha as Jantes';
    var preco =' ';
}
$('#cfg_rims').val(jantes);
return {
    jantes: jantes, 
    preco: preco
    };
}
```

HTML

```
[hidden modelo id:cfg_model]
[hidden cor id:cfg_color]
[hidden jantes id:cfg_rims]
[hidden ac id:cfg_ac]
[hidden abs id:cfg_abs]
[hidden alarme id:cfg_alarm]
[hidden led id:cfg_led]
[hidden chapeleira id:cfg_chapeleira]

<p>Oferecemos a possibilidade de enviar um email à nossa equipa com as suas escolhas no nosso configurador como manifestação de interesse, preencha o seguinte formulário e carregue em enviar para proceder ao envio da informação, a nossa equipa entrará em contacto consigo para dar seguimento à manifestação de interesse.</p>


<p>O seu Nome<br/></p>
[text* nome]

<p>O seu Email<br/></p>
[email* email]

<p>Observações<br/></p>
[textarea obs]

<p>[submit "Enviar"]</p>
```

Comment: Could you post the `html` too please? Is this function not putting the value into the `input` field?

Comment: can you add a console statement at the end of the function to print the value of the cookie and the variables

Comment: also the jslint warning is because you are using `var` in each `if` block... since javascript has only function scope you can declare them at the top `var rims_read = $.cookie('rim_color'), jantes, preco;` and remove `var` from the conditional blocks

Comment: posting the HTML in a sec :)

yeah good point, i didnt think of that, on my next restruturation i will stop redeclaring the variable, thanks 

about the console statement, how do i do that? xD sorry, im pretty new to javascript xD

Comment: Add `console.log(rims_read, jantes, preco)` before the return statement

Comment: also who is calling `readRims`

Comment: Edited to include the contact form 7 html code, this is the relevant code to this part, ignore the fact that there are many more id's in the html than in the js, this js is just part of the code, if i am to include it all, please ask.

`readRims` is called by the html in the table where i output the results to, what i tried to do here is besides just outputting to the table, i want to output to an hidden form that would take the value of each of my variables and send it by email to the user

Comment: can you share the result of logging

Comment: yes, in a minute, i just uploaded the version of the code with the logs

Comment: here, just have the [link](http://popo.com.pt/cfg/) to the page where im using the code, its easier if you could take a look, the contact form is not actually there now, but the variables should be outputting anyway

Comment: Still can't see who is calling the method... the console logs also is missing

Comment: the method `readRims` seems to be returning the correct values... need to see who is using the returned value

Comment: most of the values seems to be set except the `ac`.. there is a bug `$('#cfg_ac').val(jantes);` should be `$('#cfg_ac').val(ac);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36924/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-antero-duarte)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<table class="tab_cfg" align="center" width="70%" cellspacing="0"
    cellpadding="10">
    <tr style="border-bottom: none;">
        <th colspan="4"><br />
            <p>Abra o Configurador e siga todos os passos, a tabela abaixo
                vai mostrar os resultados que escolheu:</p></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4"><a class="readon"
            href="http://popo.com.pt/POPO/configurador/cfg/page_model/configurador_model.html"
            rel="rokbox[550 600]">Configurador</a> <a class="readon"
            href="javascript:setCookies(); document.location.reload(true)">Reset</a>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Característica</td>
        <td>Preço</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Modelo</td>
        <td><p class="modelo-modelo"></p></td>
        <td><p class="modelo-preco"></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Cor</td>
        <td><p class="color"></p></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Jantes</td>
        <td><p class="rims-jantes"></p></td>
        <td><p class="rims-preco"></p></td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1;" rowspan="6">Extras</td>
        <td>ABS</td>
        <td><p class="abs-abs"></p></td>
        <td><p class="abs-preco"></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr border="1px">
        <td>Ar Condicionado</td>
        <td><p class="ac-ac"></p></td>
        <td><p class="ac-preco"></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alarme</td>
        <td><p class="alarm-alarm"></p></td>
        <td><p class="alarm-preco"></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Luzes LED</td>
        <td><p class="led.led"></p></td>
        <td><p class="led.preco"></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-bottom: none;">
        <td>Chapeleira</td>
        <td><p class="chapeleira-chapeleira"></p></td>
        <td><p class="chapeleira-preco"></p></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        var $table = $('.tab_cfg');

        var modelo = readModel();
        $table.find('.modelo-modelo').html(modelo.modelo)
        $table.find('.modelo-preco').html(modelo.preco)

        $table.find('.color').html(readColor())

        var jantes = readRims();
        $table.find('.rims-jantes').html(jantes.modelo)
        $table.find('.rims-preco').html(jantes.preco)

        var abs = readABS();
        $table.find('.abs-abs').html(abs.modelo)
        $table.find('.abs-preco').html(abs.preco)

        var ac = readAC();
        $table.find('.ac-modelo').html(ac.modelo)
        $table.find('.ac-preco').html(ac.preco)

        var alarm = readAlarm();
        $table.find('.alarm-modelo').html(alarm.modelo)
        $table.find('.alarm-preco').html(alarm.preco)

        var led = readLED();
        $table.find('.led-modelo').html(led.modelo)
        $table.find('.led-preco').html(led.preco)

        var chapeleira = readChap();
        $table.find('.chapeleira-modelo').html(chapeleira.modelo)
        $table.find('.chapeleira-preco').html(chapeleira.preco)

    })
</script>
```

Comment: nice, thats a very good a useful post, but to a "problem" i wasnt looking to solve xD it is way cleaner though and i will implement it, thank you for that, but i was looking for a solution to writing into a contact form that i will send by email, i need a solution to fill the hidden fields using their id, not into the table, that part is working correctly :p but thank you anyway :)

Comment: just one more thing, to use this, cant i instead of have the js in a <script> tag, have it in another file and include it before the table html? im assuming it would work the same way, but im just asking to be sure

Comment: @AnteroDuarte yes.. you can

Comment: where are the hidden fields?

Comment: @AnteroDuarte found it... do you want the hidden fields to be populated when the page is loaded?

Comment: yes, that would be a solution, although im already using window.onload, but since i reload the window everytime i close the configurator, that is a good option, i couldnt get your new solution to work, it tells me preco is not defined, i tried multiple workarounds, none working, but that's not important, i can always fall back on my previous setting. the hidden fields, i dont know how they appear in the code, since it uses a wordpress plugin and shortcode, so i dont actually know how they are working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36930/discussion-between-antero-duarte-and-arun-p-johny)